# WinRT DownloadOperation doesn't return anything until either the download is complete or 1MB has downloaded

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm using the WinRT BackgroundDownloader to create a DownloadOperation and then waiting for it to call back with progress and data downloaded so far. My problem is that the callback doesn't get invoked unless the download is complete or exactly 1MB of data has been downloaded. I want to get a progress report back earlier than that.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and does anyone have a solution? I feel like there's probably a setting somewhere to change the granularity of the download progress reports but I just can't find it anywhere.

Here's a code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer;
using Windows.Storage;
```

...

```
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
var storageFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("puppy.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var downloadUri = new Uri("http://www.wallbest.com/wallpapers/2560x1600/puppy-eyes-beagle-www.wallbest.com.jpg");
var downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(downloadUri, storageFile);
var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(operation => Debug.WriteLine(operation.Progress.BytesReceived));
await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(progress);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the actual behavior: "*WinRT DownloadOperation doesn't return anything until either the download is complete or 1MB has downloaded*".
This class is intended **for downloading large files in the background**. For downloading objects smaller than 1MB you should just use asynchronous downloading using **HttpClient**.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Do you know if that's documented anywhere on MSDN? I wonder why they would impose this seemingly arbitrary limit.